# ¿Por qué me aparece esa advertencia en mi código?

Tags: c++

Quiero lograr que no tenga ninguna advertencia, ya que es programa evaluativo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Entiendo que estás hablando de C++ y no de c#, es así?

Comment: cambia todas tus variables a tipo double

Comment: Por favor no publiques imágenes de código fuente. Publica directamente el texto del fuente y de las advertencias. Un saludo.

Comment: No puedo ver la advertencia que mencionas, los colores horribles de tu captura de pantalla han quemado mis pupilas.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster por qué hay que ser "hater"?   Es mejor colaborar y pedirle que transciba el código para una mejor lectura y poderlo ayudar mejor, y me indique el error.  Al parecer nunca te has leído las reglas de la comunidad.

Comment: @AmilcarAngeles [ya se lo han pedido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264189/por-qu%c3%a9-me-aparece-esa-advertencia-en-mi-c%c3%b3digo?noredirect=1#comment487996_264189), mi comentario es más de la vertiente humorística que de la vertiente hater, un saludo.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Debes cambiar los tipos de datos de esas variables que deseas calcular a tipo double.

Los tipos reales double (o tipos de punto flotante) representan valores que contienen la parte fraccionaria. En los lenguajes de programación existen estos dos tipos para los números con punto flotante. El modo de representar los números reales en la memoria del ordenador se rige por el estándar IEEE 754 y no depende de las plataformas, sistemas operativos y lenguajes de programación.

Y estas, son las advertencias que te esta diciendo al final. Corrigelas y desapareceran.

Suerte!

Comment: @johanna si la respuesta te fue uti, marcala con un voto a favor para que si a alguien más le pasa lo mismo pueda aplicar la respuesta.

Comment: "*Los tipos reales double representan valores que contienen la parte fraccionaria.*". Esto no es cierto. Los números en coma flotante contienen tanto la parte entera como la decimal.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster,pues te invito a leer esta documentación.  Y debemos de tener cuidado al decir si es cierto o no de fomra pública sin consultar, pues otras personas se pueden confundir. No siempre nuestros concimientos son los validos. Una cosa es una fración (1 1/4) y otra cosa la parte decimal(lo que esta despues del punto) Exitos amigo!
Fuentes a consultar: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/numeric-data-types  https://www.mql5.com/es/docs/basis/types/double

Comment: Gracias por la información. Pero no he leído nada que contradiga mi información, más bien al contrario, [en el primer enlace que pasas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/numeric-data-types) ya me está dando la razón: "*no integrales tipos representan números con partes **fraccionarias y enteras***".